# SNS topic to send IAM user list to emaiil

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a python script which fetchs the IAM usernames and their last login into AWS console. I have configured the SNS topic to send the final result to my mail.But the result which i received in Email is displaying only one user name. Remaining user names are missing. Kindly help on this

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()

PhysicalString =''

for user in resource.users.all():
    if user.password_last_used is not None:
        delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
        final_result=("username: ", [user.user_name][0]," - ",str(delta) , "days")
        physicalString = 'IAM user details : \n\n' + ''.join(final_result)
        response = sns.publish(
            TopicArn='************************',
            Message= physicalString,
            Subject='IAM USER',
        )
        return final_result
```

Comment: You set the if condition to avoid the users without `password_last_used`.  Maybe that's the reason it only targets one.

Comment: That if condition excluded only users without password last used. But there are many users who had used their passwords two days before. The email output is showing only one user name but when I excute the program until final_result it is giving correct output. Issue comes When sns topic is added.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `return` *within* the `for` statement.

Therefore, the code will exit after the first user with a non-empty `password_last_used`.

Some other things are also strange:

- `PhysicalString =''` is defining a variable that is not used (with a capital `P`)
- `final_result` will only contain information for *one user*, so it is unclear what/why this information is being passed via `return`